# How can i see the configuration file of an android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I want to see the full configuration of an android emulator (android studio) and I don't know how to do it.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change configuration of an android emulator.
[image]
show detail of an android emulator.
[image]